# Is there any tool to get data from website?

Tags: json, web

Let's say I have this link called: http://user.com/1345, and that link returns a JSON. Now I want a tool that can loop from http://user.com/1 to http://user.com/1345 and save that JSON data to a file. Anyone knows a good tool for that?

Comment: Please use proper capitalization! I have fixed it for you.

Comment: voting off topic; request for tool. Also, like... shell and/or curl? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript:

```
var allData = [], xhr;
for (var i = 1; i <= 1345; i++) {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener("load", function () {
        allData.push(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
    });
    xhr.open("GET", "http://user.com/" + i);
    xhr.send();
}
window.open('data:text/json;charset=utf8,' + encodeURIComponent(allData), '_blank');
```

Comment: He wanted to save it to a file tho.

Comment: Where does this add the text to a file? It just opens a new Tab/Window? I think he wants seperate files.

Comment: @NikxDa Try this in your web console - it works :) and the OP wants to save the data "to a file" (singular).

Answer (score 0):

You can use C# to do so.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1345; i++) 
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText (i.ToString (), new WebClient.DownloadString ("http://user.com/" + (i + 1).ToString()));
```